# Semantic-ui Search Module: A valid template name was not specified

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use Semantic-ui Search Module's local search.

I can make it show no result. But when it has results, I got an error as blow:

```
Search Module: A valid template name was not specified. false
```

html code:

```
<div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui input">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
var content = [
    {
        title: 'Horse',
        description: 'An Animal'
    },
    {
        title: 'Cow',
        description: 'Another Animal'
    }
];

$('.ui.search').search({
    type   : 'simple',
    source : content,
    searchFields   : [
        'title'
    ],
    searchFullText: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[According](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1595) to the project owner, the available types are standard and category, but simple. This was an issue in documentation. He'll  adjust the documentation.

You can initialize as:

```
$('.ui.search').search({
    source : content,
    searchFields   : [
        'title'
    ],
    searchFullText: false
});
```

or

```
$('.ui.search').search({
    type: 'standard',
    source : content,
    searchFields   : [
        'title'
    ],
    searchFullText: false
});
```